# How can I delete all images that have a constant pixel value greater than 0?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, data-processing

I am trying to generate patches of an image for a machine learning piepline and the base value of the essentially black patch is 3 for some reason. As a result, I am struggling to figure out a way to delete an image if it has a constant pixel value of 3, **while also maintaining the correct pixel values of the non-black images.**

So far, my solution is to use simple pixel algebra and subtract 3 from the image. Then use the cv2.countNonZeroes() to delete the images. The issue arises when the images that contain actual important values have pixel values lower than 3 and it overflows into white. (Don't ask me why the important sections have values lower than 3, I have no clue haha!).

**How can I find find and delete the images that contain the constant value 3 while also maintaining the integrity/value of non-black (px!=3) images?**

I would also greatly appreciate any input on the re-reading in the countNonZero stage, the performance is already pretty bad, that just puts the cherry on top...

```
def generate_patches(input_dir, output_dir):
    # Define the patch size and stride
    patch_size = 448
    stride = 224

    # Loop over all files in the input directory
    for filename in os.listdir(input_dir):
    # Check if the file is an image
        if not filename.endswith('.JPG') and not filename.endswith('.png') and not filename.endswith('.jpeg'):
            continue

        # Load the input image using cv2
        input_image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(input_dir, filename), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

        ######## My Attempt ########
        input_image = input_image - 3
        ########            ########

        # Get the dimensions of the input image
        height, width = input_image.shape

        # Calculate the number of patches in each dimension
        num_rows = (height - patch_size) // stride + 1
        num_cols = (width - patch_size) // stride + 1

        # Generate patches from the input image using sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d
        patches = extract_patches_2d(input_image, (patch_size, patch_size), max_patches = num_rows * num_cols)
    
        # Reshape patches into a 2D array
        patches = patches.reshape(-1, patch_size, patch_size)

        # Loop over all patches and save them to the output directory
        for i, patch in enumerate(patches):
            patch_filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '_{}.jpg'.format(i)

            # If the image is not empty
            output = os.path.join(output_dir, patch_filename)
            cv2.imwrite(output, patch)

            ######### Here as well ##########

            input_image = cv2.imread(output, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

            # Check if all pixels in the image are black (value 0)
            if cv2.countNonZero(input_image) == 0:
                # If the image is empty, delete it
                os.remove(output)
```

Comment: Maybe  not the most efficient way, but you could use cv2.minMaxLoc and if min and max are identical, the whole image is constant.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the images, the reason you have a 3 is maybe because you are storing as JPEG which is lossy and very likely to change your pixel values. If they are computer-generated, computer graphics images, rather than photos, you may do better to avoid the issue and store as PNG.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the overflow: e.g. .png images are usually stored in uint8, meaning that you have values ranging from 0 to 2**8-1 (255). If the image is grayscale, you just have one color dimension, if the image is RGB, then you have three channels (R, G, B).

Now if you subtract 3 from values that are smaller than 3, you are causing an overflow as unsigned datatypes cannot contain negative values.

One naive approach would be to simply check if the array contains values other than 3.

Consider the following example:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.ones((512, 512)) * 3

if len(arr[arr != 3]) == 0:
    print('Image is empty!')
```

Small hint: You should probably consider checking if the image is empty first prior to storing, otherwise you are just writing and deleting the same images. By conditionally saving them if they are not considered 'empty', you are eliminate overhead and make the overarching logic cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of subtracting 3 from the image, you can directly check for the presence of any pixel with a value of 3 using numpy.
2. Use the `numpy.all()` function along with logical indexing to check if all pixels in the image have a value of 3. If all pixels are 3, then consider the image as black and delete it.

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image

def generate_patches(input_dir, output_dir):
    # Define the patch size and stride
    patch_size = 448
    stride = 224

    # Loop over all files in the input directory
    for filename in os.listdir(input_dir):
        # Check if the file is an image
        if not filename.endswith('.JPG') and not filename.endswith('.png') and not filename.endswith('.jpeg'):
            continue

        # Load the input image using cv2
        input_image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(input_dir, filename), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

        # Check if all pixels have a value of 3
        if np.all(input_image == 3):
            # If all pixels are 3, delete the image
            os.remove(os.path.join(input_dir, filename))
            continue

        # Get the dimensions of the input image
        height, width = input_image.shape

        # Calculate the number of patches in each dimension
        num_rows = (height - patch_size) // stride + 1
        num_cols = (width - patch_size) // stride + 1

        # Generate patches from the input image using sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d
        patches = image.extract_patches_2d(input_image, (patch_size, patch_size), max_patches=num_rows * num_cols)

        # Reshape patches into a 2D array
        patches = patches.reshape(-1, patch_size, patch_size)

        # Loop over all patches and save them to the output directory
        for i, patch in enumerate(patches):
            patch_filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '_{}.jpg'.format(i)
            output = os.path.join(output_dir, patch_filename)
            cv2.imwrite(output, patch)

            # Check if all pixels in the patch are black (value 0)
            if np.all(patch == 0):
                # If the patch is empty, delete it
                os.remove(output)
```